# Want to know the concept of Facebook update

Tags: facebook, live

I want to know how facebook gets live updates from the server. Did some analysis and found it use some sort of channels which keeps on dying and generating like
0-143.channel.facebook.com

Please give your ideas what it could be.
Thanks
Ankur Goel

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses javascript to pitch an ajax request to their servers at a specified time frame say like every 60 seconds or so and updates your UI accordingly if there's been updates.

get started http://jquery.com/ and more specifically http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/